# how node.js recognizes server and client side script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example in PHP we can write PHP and JavaScript code into the same file. How to write both server and client-side JavaScript code into html file?

Comment: server side js will get executed on server machine, client side javascript will get executed on client's browser. Think about this, you will get it !

Comment: @Sikorski you are right. But OP is confused about how template engine distinguishes client side javascript from node.js.

Comment: @Bibek Subedi do you even write server side code in html when it comes to nodejs ?

Comment: @Sikorski I write often. I use template engine like Jade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a templating engine like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html).

These will allow you to use server-side logic to render an HTML page before sending it to the client.

Comment: i checked Pug. as i understand there is no any tag that it can separate server and client side script in html for node.js. we should use some library like Pug and Handlebars. thank you AJ

Answer (score 1):

> *How to write both server and client-side JavaScript code into html file?*

See, NodeJs is a javascript for server and node server don't have DOM. So in your case you have to write javascript for two places one for the server and one for the browser.

As commonJs modules can't be run in the browser, where it can be used at server *(node)*.

Comment: actually it cen be possible. for example c# is a serverside language for asp.net mvc but we can use razor engine for marking c# code on the server. if a tag can be standard for node.js we can indicate server side script in html. just the idea. i am just learning nide.js. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here my simple example, I used `express` for simplicity, but I hope you can understand general idea.

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Started listen port: ' + port);
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
```

Client:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>
    console.log(200);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as i understand index.html runs on the client side. at this point i am confused. if i want to add also server side code in index.html how can i inform to node.js (Express) . for example in php we can add <php> tag for server side code. for node.js all scripts are between <script> and </script>.my question may be very stupid I apologize for that. But I am trying to learn by comparing it with the tools I use. Maybe I should change my point of view.

Comment: For this case, you need use any templating engine (handlebars, jade, etc), I've just posted simplest example...